# Glue Job to load S3 Data into Redshift Cluster in differing Region succeeding but returning no Data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I'm trying to load data from an S3 stored in EU-1 into my Redshift cluster which is stored in US-East1. I followed the steps found here  https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/create-cross-account-and-cross-region-aws-glue-connections/ and when I test the connection it comes back as "connection successful", however upon running the job it will show as complete after 1 minute but load no data into my redshift cluster.

I know the job is sound as it is a carbon copy of another job i have for the same data within US-East, just with the glue tables changed. I also know the data is there because I can view said data in the temporary S3 folder that is created by Glue upon running the job, the data is just not being moved into my Redshift Cluster and isn't returning any error messages.

Does anyone have any idea why this isn't working/how to load data from Glue in another region to your Redshift Cluster.

Comment: can you use AWS console  or system tables to see whether the data load task has run on the target redshift cluster?

Comment: It looks like it isn't running it at all on the target cluster - but i don't understand why it isn't erroring out if that was the case and is instead returning "success".

Comment: maybe update your question to include some detail - your code - your exact return message etc.